# trying to call package method using a variable

Tags: python

Im trying to store the method in a package in a variable as it might change and I dont want to manually update in multiple places in the code.

```
import hashlib as hashy

foo='hello world'
bar='hello world'

algo='md5'
hfoo=hashy.algo(foo.encode())
hbar=hashy.algo(bar.encode())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case you can use [hashlib.new()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.new) to create a hasher by its name.

```
import hashlib  # don't randomly rename standard libraries
ALGORITHM = 'md5'
h = hashlib.new(ALGORITHM)
h.update('hello world'.encode('utf-8'))
print(h.hexdigest())
```

If you think you might want to change which function in a module you're calling, you can wrap it in your own function, which is right generic answer to the question you're asking.

```
import hashlib

def hash(s):
    hashlib.md5(s.encode('utf-8'))

print hash('hello world')
```

You *can* use [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) on a module to retrieve a function by name, but that's not the usual way to do things.